# Dependency Injection with Ninject in Session_Start method of web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

iam using ninject.web extension in my web application but now i have a problem reolving a dependence in Session_Start method of global.asax

this is my global.asax

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        [Inject]
        IUserManagement um { get; set; }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (WebUser.user != null)
            {               
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[ChiaveSessioneUtente] == null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(ChiaveSessioneUtente, um.ResolveRequestingUser(Request));                   
            }     
        }
        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }   
        private void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            var modules = new List<INinjectModule>
            {
                new BusinessLogicModule(),
            };
            kernel.Load(modules);
        }
}
```

Ninject module

```
public class BusinessLogicModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IBusinessInquiry>().To<BusinessInquiry>();     
        Bind<IUserManagement>().To<UserManagement>();
    }   
}
```

but when i start application `um` is null, even if via debug i see that `CreateKernel` is executed before `Session_Start`

i also try the nuget package version of ninject.web with `NinjectWebCommon` but the result is the same: property is not injected and is null

instead in my webForm all property injected works without problem, so problem is only with `global.asax` or `session_Start` method

Comment: I am afraid you will have to add code to get your kernel and call Resolve method inside Session_Start method

Comment: so no way to avoid service locator? i just try now a service locator way and it's works fine but not so clean...

Comment: I am not really familiar with Ninject implementation, but I'm afraid injection is not applicable to some of the objects related to asp.net, and HttpApplication is in that list, because that's an entry point that allows for injection in all dependants, but not in itself. You might have to check sources for Ninject to prove that though.

Comment: I may be wrong but I am pretty sure ninject automatically injects itself after the kernel is set up if you use the web module.

Answer (score -1):

Property Setter Injection

Here’s an example of the same Samurai class using Property Setter Injection. For a property to be injected it must be annotated with [Inject].

```
class Samurai 
{    
    [Inject]
    public IWeapon Weapon { private get; set; }

    public void Attack(string target) 
    {
        this.Weapon.Hit(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: and this is what i do if you read my code, but in session_Start simply does not work

Comment: public property

Answer (score -3):

try to remove [Inject] attribute in Global.asax

Comment: I think if he were to acheive this with property injection, he will need to mark the property as public as well? (I think Ninject's default configuration is not to bind non public properties when doing property injection)

Comment: Adaam agry with you: